# what is the use case of NuxtJs asyncData?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

As far as I know  `asyncData` function in NuxtJs pages is rendered in Server-side before creating the component. And also when user navigates between pages internally after page load. `fetch` function is very similar but we can set data to `store` inside it and check if data exist in `store` on route change...

Now the question is why would I want to send a request to an API in both page refresh and route change? Isn't it better to use `fetch` function and store data in vuex store so there is no need for further API calls? what kind of data is needed to get fetched inside `asyncData` function?

For example, if I want to show a list of posts in a server-side rendered app, I think the best way is to use `fetch` property to populate the vuex `store` and after that, in every route change I will have the data inside the store and there is no need for API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case is for retrieving data that is **only relevant to a specific page**.

For example, you have several endpoints that return data about specific animals, /api/cats, /api/dogs, /api/birds.

When you load theapp.com/**cats** in your browser, the asyncData function fetches the data from /api/**cats** and renders it server-side.

Similarly, for theapp.com/dogs, it fetches /api/dogs.

The use-case changes if there is an /api/animals endpoint that contains ALL the animal data in one feed (dogs, cats and birds).

In this case, you would do the retrieval once to populate the store with all page data with something like [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

Comment: Thanks camaulay, I already know that. but the problem is: with asyncData every time a route change happens (not refresh) , data are fetched from API again and again and are not stored in vuex store...  please read my question carefully

Comment: Hey Ahmad, that is the intended behaviour of asyncData: "It will be called server-side once (on the first request to the Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further routes." - You could modify your asyncData function to check to see if the store is populated before fetching from the API, and only commit the API data to the store if the store isn't populated.